# return one column from a field in another table when adding a new record in an Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

In the sales order graph I want to get the default warehouse from the customer that has been selected on a new sales order and have it show in the External Ref. field (CustomerRefNbr in the DAC) on the sales order. 
Here is the code Ive tried. The error Im getting is "the result set is too large." 
below is the code I have placed in the attributes of the field.

```
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "External Reference")]
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<PX.Objects.CR.LocationExtAddress.cSiteID, InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<PX.Objects.CR.LocationExtAddress.bAccountID>>>, Where<PX.Objects.CR.LocationExtAddress.cSiteID, IsNotNull>>))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [PXDefault](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=96b4e224-d0d2-e2d8-671e-9ba2ed73c21b) attribute along with [PXFormula](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=43e89246-3a27-7eff-32cc-fbffcc90c74d) attribute as below

```cs
public class SOOrderEntryDemo : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search2<INSite.siteCD, InnerJoin<Location, On<Location.cSiteID, Equal<INSite.siteID>>>,
                        Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                            And<Location.locationID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerLocationID>>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Default<SOOrder.customerID, SOOrder.customerLocationID>))]
    public void SOOrder_CustomerRefNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
}
```

You can refer Acumatica help on [Overriding Attributes of a DAC field in the Graph](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d0634e8a-3a21-454c-963a-6741e7ec8390)

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to acumatica and have gone through T100 - your answer makes sense. I'm really not sure where I insert this code in the customization. I believe I override the screen level. Is that correct?

Comment: You can refer help article https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5414444d-dd54-41cb-a3ec-eaed76668cdf. That describes how to customize a field on Graph level.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - Im still missing something actual code

Answer (score 0):

The default location from locations tab in customer page doesn't include a warehouse reference.

The only default warehouse in the customer page is in the shipping settings:

[image]

I tested the following query to fetch that value:

```
PXSelectReadonly2<INSite,
InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>,
InnerJoin<LocationExtAddress, On<LocationExtAddress.locationID, Equal<BAccount.defLocationID>>>>,
Where<INSite.siteID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.cSiteID>>>
```

You can likely get the same value more directly with field `SOOrder.DefaultSiteID` which changes based on the location choosen in Sales Order document.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I don't know how to define the namespace for BAccount, LocationsExtAddress and INSite - I have     using PX.Objects; defined

Answer (score -1):

I am still missing something here - 
` public class ContractMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension
  {
    #region Event Handlers

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search2<PX.Objects.CR.Location.cSiteID,
   InnerJoin<PX.Objects.AR.Customer, On<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<XRBContrHdr.customerID>>>,
   InnerJoin<PX.Objects.CR.Location, On<PX.Objects.CR.Location.bAccountID, Equal<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID>>>>>)
  , PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
 [PXFormula(typeof(Default<PX.Objects.CR.Location.cSiteID>))]

protected virtual void XRBContrHdr_DestSiteID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
`
```